# Linting (syntax highlights) of proto3 in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, protocol-buffers, proto

Is there a way to syntax highlight (listing) of proto3 files in vscode? I've tried to use vscode-proto3, Protobuf Lint plugins, but no success so far. For example for the following example it should highlight `Date` with red as it's not defined nor imported.

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Person {
    int32 age = 1;
    string first_name = 2;
    string last_name = 3;

    // Date IN THE FOLLOWING LINE SHOULD BE HIGHLIGHTED WITH RED
    Date birthday = 9; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[vscode-proto3](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zxh404.vscode-proto3) v0.5.4 does the job for me:
[Date is underlined in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFOA1.png)

You need to save the file to trigger the validation though. Also make sure `protoc` is installed and available in your PATH, or that you've [updated the extension's setting.json](https://github.com/zxh0/vscode-proto3#extension-settings). According to their [doc](https://github.com/zxh0/vscode-proto3#syntax-validation):

> The validation is triggered when you save the proto file. You need protoc compiler to enable syntax validation. You also need a settings.json file to tell the extension the full path of protoc if it is not in path.

Answer (score 0):

[vscode-protolint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Plex.vscode-protolint) also does linting your case.

It supports [a rich set of rules backed by protolint](https://github.com/yoheimuta/protolint#rules).
Make sure `protolint` is installed and available in your PATH.

Note: I've maintained protolint.